# What is this strange-shaped fruit?

Tags: species-identification, botany, fruit

[image]

[image]

[image]

The fruit has form of a cube or icosaheder. It is green but quickly becomes black. The meat of ripe fruit is easily separated from the seed, is sweet and tastes as dried plum. The seed has strange icosahedrical form, like two pyramids connected.

The fruit is seen on Mediterranean coast of Israel.

Comment: I don't have the answer, but a warning: the flowers, to the degree I can see them, look like the family Apocynaceae -- 5 petals, tubular, twisted/overlapping petals.  Break off a leaf and see if there is white sap, another characteristic of the family.  These plants are typically very toxic, at least the sap containing parts.  However, the fruit looks pretty atypical for the Apocynaceae, and I don't know if the fruit in the family is typically toxic.  But I guess you've already done the experiment!

Comment: @Bryan Hanson: And if the OP never posts again, we can reasonably assume that it was indeed toxic :-)

Comment: You funny! Let’s hope we get a positive report!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Now I have the answer, and if you are reading this soon after eating the fruit you should probably seek medical attention.

Looks like [Cascabela theviata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascabela_thevetia) which is in the Apocynaceae and the Wikipedia article makes clear that the fruit is also poisonous.

Comment: I did not eat it, only tried yesterday morning, I experienced no problems so far.

Comment: @Anixx that's good to hear!  I think it could have been unpleasant...

Comment: I did not swallow it, that's why possibly there are no effects. But I testify it tastes like a dried plum.